# Can this query be written better?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is one of the queries written to retrieve data for an Automation Suite:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT CARR_TRAK_I,IBND_HDR_I FROM CTNR WHERE IBND_HDR_I IN 
  (SELECT IBND_HDR_I FROM IBND_HDR WHERE ORD_I IN 
  (SELECT ORD_I FROM IBND_HDR WHERE IBND_HDR_I IN 
  (SELECT top 1 IBND_HDR_I FROM CTNR WHERE CARR_TRAK_I IN 
  (SELECT CARR_TRAK_I FROM CTNR WHERE STAT_C = 0 and IBND_HDR_I IN 
  (SELECT IBND_HDR_I FROM IBND_HDR WHERE ORD_I IN 
  (SELECT ORD_I FROM IBND_HDR WHERE IBND_STAT_C =0 and STR_I  = 3456 GROUP BY ORD_I HAVING count(ORD_I) >1)) 
  GROUP BY CARR_TRAK_I HAVING count(CARR_TRAK_I)>1)))) 
  ORDER BY IBND_HDR_I ASC
```

Can this query be written in a better way?

I am not looking for optimization as time of retrieval is not a priority for me. I am asking for any other techniques or ways available to write the same which is better than the above query.

Hope I am making myself clear!
Just want to master the SQL writing skills :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using inner joins instead of nested queries, much easier to read and understand.

This should get you started...

```
select distinct CTNR.CARR_TRAK_I, CTNR.IBND_HDR_I 
from CTNR 
INNER JOIN IBND_HDR
ON CTNR.IBND_HDR_I = IBND_HDR.IBND_HDR_I
INNER JOIN...
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever one to one relation-ship, you can use inner join. When you want to group by or top1 like query, use inner query  as below.

There is some more space for optimization, but do not sample data to verify the output.
you can do the same logic in inner query at your end. and if possible give the sample data to verify output.

please check this sample.

```
select 
    distinct C.CARR_TRAK_I,C.IBND_HDR_I 
from CTNR C
INNER JOIN IBND_HDR IH ON C.IBND_HDR = IH.IBND_HDR
INNER JOIN IBND_HDR IH1 ON  IH.ORD_I = IH1.ORD_I AND IH1.IBND_HDR_I in 
    (
        select top 1 IBND_HDR_I from CTNR C1
        INNER JOIN CTNR C2 ON C1.CARR_TRAK_I = C2.CARR_TRAK_I AND STAT_C = 0 
        INNER JOIN IBND_HDR IBH2 ON IBH2.IBND_HDR_I = C1.IBND_HDR_I AND IBH2.ORD_I IN               
        (
            select top 1 IBND_HDR_I from CTNR where CARR_TRAK_I in 
            (
                select CARR_TRAK_I from CTNR where STAT_C = 0 and IBND_HDR_I in (
                select IBND_HDR_I from IBND_HDR where ORD_I in 
                (select ORD_I from IBND_HDR where IBND_STAT_C =0 and STR_I  = 3456 group by ORD_I having count(ORD_I) >1)) 
                group by CARR_TRAK_I having count(CARR_TRAK_I)>1
            )
        )
    )
```